# How to debug inside performBatchUpdates

Tags: ios, swift

I append objects in the `collectionView` model inside `performBatchUpdates`, something like that :

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

for item in items{
// Append the different objects... example:
if item is Picture{
 self.modelCollection.append(item, cellReuseIdentifier: "Picture")
}

}

 }, completion: { completed in

 self.isRefreshing = false
```

I am sorry but I can't post the original code. This code is inside a function called after the data is reloaded or when the device orientation changes to rearrange the collectionView cells. When the device is reloading the data and the orientation change at the same time I get an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for index path
>   for global index 536870881 when there are only 31 items in the
>   collection view'

I know it's not easy to understand the problem without the complete code but my problem consist on how to debug this error? I am almost sure that the problem is inside performBatchUpdates.I put a beakpoint in every single line but I get the error only in the `completion` closure without any other informations. Do you have an idea on what is going on or how to debug this ?

Comment: According to the errorcode you are requesting an item index path beyond whats actually in the datasource. What you can do is to: 1: log the number of items in the datasource. 2: log the indexpath of the items you try to access/change and see if that indexpath is beyond what exists in the datasource. 3: Try "reloaddata" on the collectionview instead of performbatchupdates and see if the crash exists there, if it does not, it might be that your item actually is added but later on, and you actually try to access it before its added etc. Logging is your best friend here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What do you mean reloaddata instead of performbatchupdates ? Append all the objects in the collectionView and then cal reloaddata ?

Comment: Your collectionview datasource MUST reflect the changes you do in the performBatchUpdates. Otherwise you will crash. That means, BEFORE you add items/changes in the performbatchupdates, your datasource must contain the actual changes you want to perform, otherwise you insert items that does not exist. So make sure you add the "pictures" to the datasource BEFORE you do the performbatchupdates.

Comment: I tried to remove performbatchupdates and the bug is not there anymore.

Comment: ella87, then you are probably trying to insert/edit wrong items that does not reflect the datasource connected to the collectionview. Thats why you get the crash.

Comment: What I am doing wrong is inside performbatchupdates or not necessarily? I am still unable to locate the problem.

Comment: Please read my last comment that is your solution . You need to update the DATASOURCE of the collectionview BEFORE you run "performbatchupdates". The "items" array can NOT be your datasource, you need for example "datasourceArray" , and you loop your "items" array BEFORE batchupdates, you add all the pictures to your DATASOURCE, after you do that, you then run the performBatchUpdates to reflect the changes you made to your datasource. Check this example: https://gist.github.com/gkoehler/ac63ffbcfd147227c82b